# C: Redirect output of system() to stderr

Tags: c

The C system() call runs a program and forwards both stdout and stderr of the command that is run to the stdout and stderr streams of the calling program.

Is it possible to redirect stdout from the command inside the system() call to the stderr stream of the calling program?

Comment: here what you need is not `system`, but `fork` then `dup2` then one of `exec`.(assuming you are working on Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append `1>&2` to the command executed in your system call:

---

Example:

```
system("ls 1>&2");
```

will execute `ls` and redirect stdout (1) to stderr (2).

Comment: (This works because system doesn't just execute the program, it runs a shell and executes the string in there, so you can use shell redirect operators. This is usually dangerous, though (if you improperly escape a parameter in your command, people can inject operators and malicious commands), so you should be using fork/exec instead, which let you provide file descriptors that stdout etc. will go to)